# Python script to count the number of records in a file on Google cloud bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-bucket

Can you please help on providing python script to capture count of records in a file that is on GCS.
Im trying to connect from linux server to GCS Bucket and capture the count of records/size of file.

Comment: What's a record for you? (line?) and what did you try until now?

Comment: Record means, number of lines in the file........I havent made any progress in creating the script, going through GCP  and python commands to connect to GCS bucket.....If you have any thoughts , Please share.....Thanks for your response

Comment: This is the one, im looking into to get some idea and thoughts around implementing this requirement
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/HEAD/python/demo/main.py

Comment: Yes, read file and count the line.

Comment: Hi, have you tried guillaume's suggestion? also what is the file type from where you want to count the number of records?

Comment: Hello @ZeenathSN - Thats for read file only or count number of files, we need record count in a fie stored in a variable, it is a mainframe cobol file.

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible code, see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

I  am using the following script and it’s working for me, I hope you can get an idea through this on how to do it.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import storage
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
storage_client = storage.Client()
file_data = 'file_name'
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
temp_file_name = 'file_ma,e'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_data)
blob.download_to_filename(temp_file_name)
 
temp_str=''
with open (temp_file_name, "r") as myfile:
   for count, line in enumerate(myfile):
       pass
print('Total Lines', count + 1)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

I have first downloaded the file in my environment using download_to_filename() and then later I have read the file using open(). I have used enumerate() inside the for loop that adds a counter, you can read more about the enumerate [here](https://pynative.com/python-count-number-of-lines-in-file/).

Comment: Thanks @Zeenath...Will try and let you know